# q-municate message support for pdf, audio and video files in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox, q-municate

How can I integrate the support for pdf files, audio and video files in Quickblox application / q-municate on IOS platform.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is in development. Follow [our blog](https://quickblox.com/blog/) to keep track of updates.